# How do I check for the following instanceof in Java?

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for a better way to do the following:

```
class Animal {}

class Dog extends Animal
class Cat extends Animal
class Rat extends Animal
class Bat extends Animal
.. 50 such animals
```

Now I have a list of animals - `List<Animal>`.

I want to do something like this:

```
for (Animal animal : animalList) {
   if (animal instanceof (Dog or Cat or 1 of 10 such animals) ) {
      //do something with animal.
   }
}
```

What is a good way to check wither this animal is an instance of a sublist if animals besides doing 10 instanceof checks?

Comment: A better way is to apply polymorphism and SOLID principles: make methods in your abstract classes which behave how you want, then call those methods on any `Animal`. The fact they're subclasses will work out distinguishing which code to run. Not to mention applying interfaces for behavior to classes you need (`public interface Edible`, anyone?)

Comment: I really wish I could, but the Animal abstract class is in a 3rd party library that I cannot modify. And the cost of creating a subclass from the Animal class and make all the classes extend from it is gonna be too much of a refactoring at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Rogue's comment:

Have **Animal** methods to differentiate subclasses like for example
`Animal.isMammal()`
or `Animal.hasFourLegs()`

Then the subclasses have properties like `Dog.isMammal = true`
or `Bat.hasFourLegs = false`

Comment: This sounds like the better solution. Whatever behaviour you mean to check for, make a method on Animal where you can make the distinction using method polymorphism rather than hard-coded lists of subclasses.

Comment: Is there a way I can provide a default implementation for isMammal considering I'm using Java1.7 and I cannot provide a default implementation in the Animal interface?

Answer (score 1):

The direct approach would be:

```
for (Animal animal : animalList) {
   for (Class clz : myClassSubList) {
      if (clz.isInstance(animal)) {
         //do something with animal.
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

edited: as per @shmosel's comment

Comment: "`animal instanceof clz`" Are you sure?

Comment: Definitely not.

Comment: You would have to do `clz.isInstance(animal)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class AnimalSubgroup extends Animal
class Dog extends AnimalSubgroup
class Cat extends AnimalSubgroup
if (animal instanceof AnimalSubgroup) {
    // do thing
}
```

Another advantage of this approach is if there are common properties or methods that these animals should share, they can go in the abstract class.